# Custom canvas class serialization

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a class with some properties which I want to serialize. My problem is that 
I can't serialize the "CustomCanvasClass". I only need the X/Y properties of it. 
So I created a new property and marked the "CustomCanvasClass" property as [NonSerialized].

Unfortunatly it won't works. Maybe have somebody another idea to copy this data out of the class.

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomClass
{
    //won't serialized
    public double X
    {
        get
        {
            return Canvas.GetLeft(CustomCanvasClass);
        }

        set
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(CustomCanvasClass, value);
        }
    }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    //CanvasElement inherits from Canvas. Serialization would throw a Exception.
    public CanvasElement CustomCanvasClass
    {
        get
        {
            return _CustomCanvasClass;
        }
        set
        {
            _CustomCanvasClass = value;
        }
    }

    [NonSerialized]
    private CanvasElement _CustomCanvasClass;
}
```

Comment: Canvas.Left and Top are attached properties which are... ermm... attached... to the children of a canvas. Should that be: Canvas.GetLeft(this)

Comment: I'm not too clear what you're doing here. A fairly standard way to render a collection of objects out into things in a canvas is to make that canvas the itemspanel of an itemscontrol. Bind a collection of viewmodels - each of which defines the content data for a piece of ui like a shape which will be rendered in the canvas. Then define a datatemplate for each viewmodel type. You can then serialise the viewmodel which is the parent of all those viewmodels. This is how the map editor in our game works. EG There's a woodsvm which is rendered into something representing woods.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your answers! I'll try currently the DTO solution. I've different "Element" model-classes which all inherit the same interface. A collection of it is bound to a Itemscontrol. The control is in a tabcontrol with a viewmodel each tab. It works fine. The serialization is one of the last things which are still missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a DTO for the properties you need and serialize that.

DTO stands for data transfer object. It contains data you want to transfer only and no logic.

E.g. Add a class like this:

```
class MyCustomClassDto
{
    public double X {get;set;}
    public double Y {get;set;}
}
```

So instead of trying to serialize your custom class directly, you would initialize an instance of this with your X and Y values and serialize that.

Then in your main class you could add this:

```
public MyCustomClassDto GetData()
{
    return new MyCustomerClassDto{X = X, Y = Y};
}
```

You could add a serialization method to your DTO also.

Alternatively you can use a mapping tool like automapper - which would be suitable if you have many DTOs or corresponding objects in different layers.

Hope that makes the idea clear. Can't see other ways of expanding without seeing more details/context.

The proper mvvm itemspanel approach in the comment on the question is preferable, but it might require substantial rewriting depending on your existing codebase. You might want to consider the business case for such refactoring imo, considering the effort against how much more is likely to be built on top of it.

Comment: Can you explain me please how it works. I looked in the documentation but I dont understand. The property "X" is like a dto, or not?

Comment: @user23623447 I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a great answer. It's more a comment and I guess people are likely to downvote it as is. I recommend you expand much more.